# Нужна ли запятая после местоимения "что"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Олег понял, что(,) съедая каждое утро овсяную кашу с ягодами, всё равно оставался голодным до самого обеда.*

Я правильно понимаю, что "съедая каждое утро овсяную кашу с ягодами" - это деепричастный оборот? Значит, запятая нужна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, разумеется, ***запятая нужна.*** Тем более что если изъять всё придаточное со "что",
то получится белиберда, а если изъять один деепричастный оборот, то останется вполне осмысленное высказывание.